# TFS sends notifications to wrong email address

Tags: tfs

We have TFS 2018 on premises. The TFS data was historically migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2016 and subsequently to TFS 2018. One of the old projects was set up to send TFS code review notifications to all project team's individual members. All notifications are delivered to correct email addresses except one developer. When I open the project notification sent to me, I can see that notification was sent to misspelled address of this developer. This explains why TFS notification was not delivered to the developer. I don;t know where this address was taken from because her email address looks ok in her TFS profile web page. When she changes her preferred email to another address, notifications are still sent to the wrong misspelled address. Interestingly, the recently created TFS projects do not have this problem. All notifications are sent to her email address which matches her AD address. I am puzzled. Is notification email address is stored on a project level in TFS? How can I fix this? Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to correct address from TFS web portal.Therefore,  I just searched all TFS databases for misspelled email address. I found two columns were misspelled address was stored: TFSDefaultCollection.tbl_EventSubscription.Address and TFSDefaultCollection.tbl_EventNotification.NotificationMetadata. Both tables were updated with correct email address.